# Is it correct to use the word "free" in the sense if not being busy?

Tags: word-choice

Is the use of the verb **free** correct in the following sentence?

> I am **free** on Monday, so we could go out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a common idiom. The idea is that you have time that is not obligated to others.